# Create complicated conditional column (geometric mean) Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a column in a df that will tell me whether or not water at a given time was of swimmable quality. I'm hitting a wall though with geometric mean.

This is a mini sample df like what I'm working with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Site': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'], 'EnteroCount': [1733, 4, 20, 150, 70, 1500, 55, 22, 180]})
df["Site"] = df["Site"].astype('category')
```

These are the conditions that make water unacceptable for swimming:
EnteroCount >= 110
OR
**five or more samples with a geometric mean (a weighted average) greater than 30**

I want to create a column that just assigns a value "acceptable" or "unacceptable" based on both of these conditions. I can do the following for the first condition, but bringing in the gmean isn't so easy (or is it?):

```
df['swim'] = np.where(df['EnteroCount']>=110, 'unacceptable', 'acceptable')
```

Would love to see how this can be done efficiently.

Comment: I am not clear on how you want to compute your geometric average or how you obtain your samples.  Is each record a sample, so you want those with five or more values greater than 30?

Comment: "Five or more samples with a geometric mean" which five samples? Geometric mean for a particular site? And do you want to decide on sample level or site level?

Comment: could you provide more data on what the geometric mean is actually computed on ? Otherwise you can just add an or condition to np.where

Comment: I'm looking for geometric mean of a particular site's EnteroCount. So grouping by Site, do any 5 samples have a geometric mean greater than 30? I'm working with someone else's description of water quality.

Comment: This is unfortunately the only information I have for computing the geometric mean: "The federal standard for unacceptable water quality is a single sample value of greater than 110 Enterococcus/100mL, or five or more samples with a geometric mean (a weighted average) greater than 30 Enterococcus/100mL." The full data is here:`data_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jlaurito/CUNY_IS608/master/lecture4/data/riverkeeper_data_2013.csv"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This calculates the geometric mean of each site and checks if it is greater than 30:

```
>>> df['geo_mean_acceptable'] = (
        df.groupby('Site')
          .transform(lambda group: group.prod() ** (1 / float(len(group))) > 30)
          .astype(bool))
```

And this gets the geometric mean of each site:

```
>>> df.groupby('Site').EnteroCount.apply(lambda group: group.product() ** (1 / float(len(group))))
Site
A     68.016702
B    121.981006
C    180.000000
Name: EnteroCount, dtype: float64
```

Using the geometric mean function from scipy:

```
from scipy.stats.mstats import gmean

>>> df.groupby('Site').EnteroCount.apply(gmean)
Site
A     68.016702
B    121.981006
C    180.000000
Name: EnteroCount, dtype: float64
```

Given that the five highest values will give you the highest geometric mean in a group, you can use this:

```
df.groupby('Site').EnteroCount.apply(lambda group: gmean(group.nlargest(5)))
```

You can see how it is selecting the largest five values by group, which then get used as parameters for `gmean`:

```
>>> df.groupby('Site').EnteroCount.apply(lambda group: group.nlargest(5).values.tolist())
Site
A    [1733, 150, 70, 20, 4]
B            [1500, 55, 22]
C                     [180]
Name: EnteroCount, dtype: object
```

**Summary**

```
df['swim'] = np.where(
    (df.groupby('Site').EnteroCount.transform(max) > 110) |
    (df.groupby('Site').EnteroCount.transform(lambda group: gmean(group.nlargest(5))) > 30), 
    'unacceptable', 'acceptable')
```